# i does not let me inser the matrice that i want

Tags: for-loop, printing, numbers, insertion-sort, rotational-matrices

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int a[2][2];
    //inserting the numbers
    printf("entrer  la matrice\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
                printf("entrer la ligne %d colonne %d\n",i,j );
                scanf("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            // printing the numbers that i just put
            printf("%d",a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the problem more precisely.

Comment: i forgot an & in front of scanf